# Como passar objeto para outra view no JSF?

Tags: java, jsf

Qual melhor maneira de passar um objeto para outra view no JSF?

Tenho duas paginas uma de consulta e outra com os dados para editar determinado objeto, a pagina de consulta tem uma lista de objetos e cada objeto tem o botão editar que faz com que redirecione para a pagina de edição, não consigo enviar o objeto e carregar na pagina de edição.
Meu Bean estou usando ViewScoped.

Em outras linguagens é possível passar por POST mas em java é meio complicado não estou conseguindo se adaptar. 
Se possível coloquem um trecho de código.

Comment: Vejo duas alternativas simples: Como atributo do Request, se for usar *forward* ou como atributo no Flash, se for usar redirect.

Comment: Já tentou usar um `f:setPropertyActionListener`? Baseando em um sistema de CRUD, acredito que funcionaria muito bem. O botão faria o redirecionamento, e dentro das tags do botão vc setaria o `f:setPropertyActionListener` com o modelo de dado a ser enviado, o codigo seria mais ou menos esse: `<f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{bean.objeto}" value="#{objeto}">`.

Comment: Pela melhor experiência de usuário e para maior simplicidade de design, recomendo: cada botão deve ser um link para a URL da página de edição, passando o ID do objeto como parâmetro. Na página de edição você recarrega o objeto a partir deste ID recebido por parâmetro. Use SessionScoped apenas para manter dados que são naturalmente da sessão como credenciais do usuário e suas preferências.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O escopo de View (*View Scope*) é descartado sempre que ocorre uma navegação de uma tela para outra.

Uma alternativa é armazenar o objeto no escopo de Sessão (*Session Scope*).

Também é possível passar o ID do objeto um parâmetro de URL ou no *Flash Scope* e então carregá-lo novamente na página de destino.

Comment: Ok, mas se eu deixar SessionScoped quando o usuario navegar em outra pagina e voltar para a pagina de cadastro os dados vão estar la, poderia exemplificar com códigos?

Comment: @JuarezA.FrancoJunior Os dados vão estar lá se você não fizer nada, mas você pode limpar ou resetar os dados no método que redireciona para a tela. Infelizmente estou sem tempo hábil para elaborar uma resposta mais detalhada com códigos, pois teria que ressuscitar alguns projetos que não mexo há algum tempo.

Comment: @utluiz, tentei implementar com o código da resposta abaixo e não funcionou. Você pode elaborar uma resposta mais concreta?

Answer (score -1):

Setando o objeto no Flash Scope

```
String str = "teste";

FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getFlash().put("teste", str);
```

Na outra Bean crie um método e utilize anotação `@PostConstruct`.

```
@PostConstruct
public void init() {
     String strAux = (String) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getFlash().get("teste");
}
```

É possível passar uma List.

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getFlash().put(LISTA_STRING, listaString);

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
     List<String> listaString = (List<String>) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getFlash().get(LISTA_STRING);
}
```

Comment: Amigo, tentei implementar dessa maneira usando o init na outra bean. Mais ela tá vindo Null. Sabe porquê?